# XStream: could not access field with implementation of abstract class

Tags: java, reflection, xstream

In my project I use XStream to serialize/deserialize my entities.
Everythings works fine in the application but not when I trie to create some unit tests.
I have an abstract class `A` with a field `name` and public accessors. I have a class `B` that extends `A`. 
My XStream configuration is like this one:

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
//
xStream.alias("classNameSerialized", AnotherClass.class);
xStream.aliasAttribute(AnotherClass.class, OBJECT_ATTRIBUT_VERSION, OBJECT_ATTRIBUT_VERSION);
...
//
xStream.alias("classNameSerialized", B.class);
xStream.aliasAttribute(B.class, "name", "name");
```

When I run my application, there is no problem. But when I try to create an unit test, XStream fires the exception: `IllegalArgumentException: could not access org.mycompagny.B.name field: name`
**EDIT**
I tried in my test `B.class.getDeclaredField("name");` and it throws me the same exception. But when I try `A.class.getDeclaredField("name");` there is no problem. I understand that it can be a problem whith the reflection, but what I cannot understand is why this problem appears just in my unit test and not in my application... 
The final question is how can I test this code???

Comment: If the field is declared in `A`, you need `xStream.aliasAttribute(A.class, "name", "name");`. Or even easier, you can use annotations and then this kind of problem is side-stepped completely. As for why it works in your application, you probably have the alias for `name` field defined for `A.class` somewhere, which is why it works.

Comment: @biziclop I wish I could use annotations but in fact depending of the class that extends the abstract class I have other mapping to put in place. That's why I have to do it with some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my problem I had to delete my abstract class...
In my case it was not a big problem, only 5 classes inherited from the abstract class.
If somebody has a better solution, post it here ;-)